# Bypass other .htaccess files after RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

The problem I am facing is related to CakePHP and I will explain it in that context but it really is a mod_rewrite issue:

In CakePHP, all requests are routed into the `/app/webroot` directory. In that directory, I have another directory called `assets` in which all the user-uploaded files are stored. I now want to be able to serve thumbnails for every image in that folder, and I want to auto-generate and then cache them on the first request.

To do that, I have a `.htaccess` file in the `assets` directory, which is supposed to route all requests that start with `thumbs/` to a PHPThumb script. Now I could simply put said script into the `assets` directory and everything would work fine. But:

1. I want to avoid file bloat (as there can be multiple resolution thumbnails and so on) and would therefore much rather store those thumbnails in the `/app/tmp` directory,
2. The whole thing is part of a CakePHP plugin I am developing, so it would be neat if the script could stay in the Plugin's folder.

What I have tried (inside the `/app/webroot/assets` directory):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^thumbs\/([^\/]*)\/(.*)$ ../../Plugin/MyPlugin/Lib/thumbnail.php?size=$1&path=$2 [QSA,L,S=2]
```

Now this doesn't work. The problem are the `.htaccess` files in `/app` and `/app/webroot` which route everything to `/app/webroot/index.php` (or any physical file in `webroot`). The `S` flag only seems to apply to rules in the same file.

I obviously could change those files to allow `thumbnail.php` but as I said, its part of a Plugin and I would prefer to keep it as configuration-less as possible.

So my question: Is there a way to bypass/disable any other rewrite rules after the one in `/app/webroot/assets/.htaccess` was applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problems

There are two big-ish problems in the code in the question:

1. Mixing mod rewrite with, well any FrontController-style php code
2. Trying to route to a php file that is *supposed* to be inaccessible

The only php file that is supposed to be web accessible for a production CakePHP application is `webroot/index.php`

### Create a controller action

The right way to do what you're asking is to create a route and a controller action:

Route:

```
<?php
// app/Config/routes.php
Router::connect(
    '/thumbs/*, 
    array('controller' => 'thumbs', 'action' => 'serve')
);
```

Controller:

```
<?php
// app/Controller/ThumbsController.php
class ThumbsController extends AppController {

    function serve() {
        // resize file, 
        //(preferably write to the request uri) 
        //and serve the image
    }
}
```

The controller action can use [send-file](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cake-response-file) (or [media views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html) in older versions) to send the file contents after resizing.

### Cache in a web-accessible path

Note that serving files with php [is always slow](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/themes.html#increasing-performance-of-plugin-and-theme-assets):

> It’s a well known fact that serving assets through PHP is guaranteed to be slower than serving those assets without invoking PHP.

If at all possible, make sure that the request for a thumb image is processed and written to the same url as the request (or a different location, with an appropriate edit to the .htaccess file - [here's an example](https://github.com/mcurry/html_cache/blob/master/extras/webroot.htaccess)) so that the next time the same image is requested - it is served directly via apache. If a caching technique is implemented in any form whereby php is part of a request for a cached image - the caching is not going to be particularly effective.

Comment: Yes well my next step would have been to first route to the `tmp` directory to check if the file already exists.

Soo.. Thumbs in `webroot`?

Comment: Ok, I now have implemented it the way you suggested and everything worked out just fine! Thanks a lot.